# Decompose $\frac{1}{a \sin x +b}$ into sum of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I am wondering if it is possible to write

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{a \sin x +b}$$

as a sum of functions that don't have trigonometric functions in the denominator? Or just pure trigonometric functions, without a constant added. So maybe something like this:

$$\frac{1}{a \sin x +b}=A\sin^3 x \cos^2x + B\sin x \cos ^4 x + C\frac{1}{\cos x}+ D\frac{\cos^2 x }{\sin x}+\dots $$

The reason I'm asking is that I need to integrate products of $f(x)$ with powers $\cos^n x$, and it would be really neat to get rid of the constant in the denominator, as integrals of the form $\int\frac{\cos^n x}{a \sin x +b}dx$ are extremely hard to solve, whereas integral tables contain solutions to $\int \sin^p x \cos^q x dx$ and similar integrals.

One potential starting point could be

$$\frac{1}{a \sin x +b}=\frac{a \sin x -b}{(a \sin x +b)(a \sin x -b)}=\frac{a \sin x -b}{(a^2 \sin^2 x -b^2)}=...$$
with the goal to eventually make the replacement $\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x =1$. Can such a method be formalized? Or is the decomposition I have in mind *provable* not possible? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin (x)+k}$$
If $k\ll 1$, you could use  expansions and write
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \csc^{n+1} (x)\,k^n$$
If $k\gg 1$, you could use  expansions and write
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sin^{n}(x) \,k^{-(n+1)} $$

Comment: Hm interesting... unfortunately, $k$ in general is neither $\ll 1$ or $\gg 1$; it could also be negative. But what are these expansions? They could be useful going forward. Do you have a reference? Thanks!

Comment: @Minow. Just Taylor series if you want

Comment: I think yours is the method of choice in this case. Consider the geometric series: $\frac{1}{1-q}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty q^k$ for $|q|<1$. In our case, for a<b, $\frac{1}{a\sin x+b}=\frac{1}{b(a/b\sin x+1)}$, so $|a/b\sin x|<1$. Overall, we arrive at $\frac{1}{a\sin x+b}=\frac{1}{b}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-a/b)^k\sin^k x$. This is very similar to your Taylor series approach, but it doesn't require $a/b \ll1$, only $a/b <1$. Thanks, though! And it avoids integrating sines of different frequency which the Fourier series approach requires, but it is also very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $b>a$ such that $b+a\sin(x)\ne0$. Then, per the Fourier series

$$\frac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{b+a\sin(x)}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}-b}{a}\right)^n[\sin\frac{n\pi}2\sin{(nx )}+ \cos\frac{n\pi}2\cos{(nx )} ]$$

Comment: Sorry for picking this up after such long time, where did you get that decomposition from?

Answer (score 1):

An idea for a solution just came to my mind, which I am going to post here hoping it might be useful for somebody in the future. Unfortunately, the condition doesn't work in my case, so that I might go with the Fourier series solution. But for $a\geq b$, we can write

$$\frac{1}{a \sin x +b}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{\sin x +\frac{b}{a}}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{\sin x +\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{2\sin\left(\frac{x+\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x-\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}{2}\right)}.$$

Trigonometric expansion with Mathematica yields

$$\frac{1}{2\sin\left(\frac{x+\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x-\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}{2}\right)}\\=\frac{1}{2} \sec \left(\frac{c}{2}\right) \sec (c) \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sec \left(\frac{c}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \csc \left(\frac{c}{2}\right) \sec (c) \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \csc \left(\frac{c}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right)+\csc (c)$$

with $c=\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$.

Comment: Nice solution !